# Cargar una Base de Datos Postgresql y Sequelize con datos de Api Externa

Tags: nodejs, postgresql

Estoy tratando de cargar datos desde una api externa a mi base de datos Postgresql y ORM Sequelize. En mi código tengo una función para llamar a la api y extraer los datos que necesito, luego necesito guardarlos a mi base de datos para que al hacer la consulta los traiga desde la Bd y no desde la Api externa, pero cuando hago el request lo que me trae es un array vacío, como si no los estuviera cargando a la base.

**Este es mi código**

```
const sequelize = require ('sequelize')
const axios = require ('axios');
const { Country } = require ('../db.js');

async function getAllCountries (req, res){
    try { 
        const allCountries = await axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3/all')
        const dataAll=  allCountries.data
        const countries = dataAll.map(el => {
            return {
            id: el.cca3,
            nombre: el.name.common,
            imagen: el.flags != null ? el.flags[0] : el.flags == 'No data',
            continente: el.region,
            capital: el.capital != null? el.capital[0] : el.capital == 'No data',
            sub_region: el.subregion,
            area: el.area,
            poblacion: el.population
        }        
    });
```

```
        countries.forEach( el => {
        Country.findOrCreate({
            where: {
                id: el.id,
                nombre : el.nombre,
                imagen: el.imagen,
                continente: el.continente,
                capital: el.capital,
                sub_region: el.sub_region,
                area: el.area,
                poblacion: el.poblacion
                
           }     
        }) 
        
    }) 
        
 } catch (err){
   next (err)
}} 

         async function countries ( req, res, next ) {
         try{
             const getCountries = await Country.findAll()
             console.log(getCountries)
             res.status(200).send(getCountries)

    }catch(err){
        next(err)
    }
 
}
```

```
module.exports = {
        countries,
        getAllCountries
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que me responde cuando hago la consulta

```
[]
GET /countries/ 200 109.428 ms - 2
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido @KDVSL. No está claro que es Country, si es un array que estás intentando escribir habría que ver que son los métodos findOrCreate y  findAll.
Si Country es el modelo heredando los métodos de Model(de sequelize), entonces la sintaxis del findOrCreate es incorrecta, por otro lado debería llevar un await. No se puede utilizar await dentro de un forEach, reemplazaría este por un forof quizás. Creo que falta información para terminar de entender el código, quizás puedas mejorar la pregunta.
Te sugiero leer [ask] para evitar calificaciones negativas o el cierre de la pregunta.

Comment: También buscaría la forma de reducir las interacciones con la base de datos, hacer un create por cada iteración podría ser resuelto generando el array primero con la estructura final (lo que entiendo ya hacés en el map) y hacer una única interacción con la base de datos con el método bulkCreate